# Timer seems to be firing twice in command line battle simulator

Tags: c#, .net, linq, timer

I'm trying to create a base class that implements attacking and receiving damage from an attacker using a System.Timers.Timer object to fire attack events, which the target responds to by reducing its HP, and signaling when it is destroyed.

The weird part is that the timer seems like it is firing the AttackTarget elapsed handler twice in a row, but only when it would result in the target being destroyed.

The test I did looks fine for the first 4 attacks, then immediately after that (no 1000ms delay), the 5th attack happens somehow, and the destroyed messages appear, even though the target still has 1 hp left after the 4th attack.

I set up a breakpoint on the AttackTarget method, and I can see from the output also, that the AttackTarget event only fires 4 times for Barbarian, which should leave the target with 1 hp, but instead the target seems to respond to the TakeDamage 5 times, and reports being destroyed.

I might be able to reduce the code necessary to reproduce the problem, but it should be easy enough to paste the code into a single project if you'd like to test it out and try to find out what I'm doing wrong.

## Sample output

```
Barbarian attacking at 1005 time elapsed
Goblin attacking at 1006 time elapsed
Goblin took 8 damage from Barbarian. 25 hp remaining.
Barbarian took 11 damage from Goblin. 45 hp remaining.
Barbarian attacking at 2000 time elapsed
Goblin took 8 damage from Barbarian. 17 hp remaining.
Goblin attacking at 2000 time elapsed
Barbarian took 11 damage from Goblin. 34 hp remaining.
Barbarian attacking at 3000 time elapsed
Goblin took 8 damage from Barbarian. 9 hp remaining.
Goblin attacking at 3001 time elapsed
Barbarian took 11 damage from Goblin. 23 hp remaining.
Barbarian attacking at 4001 time elapsed
Goblin took 8 damage from Barbarian. 1 hp remaining.
Goblin attacking at 4001 time elapsed
Barbarian took 11 damage from Goblin. 12 hp remaining.
Barbarian did 8 damage to Goblin and destroyed it!
Goblin destroyed at 4003 time elapsed
```

## My test program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ClashOfClans.Units.Troops;

namespace TestClashOfClans
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var b1 = new Goblin(1);
            var a1 = new Goblin(1);
            b1.EngageTarget(a1);
            a1.EngageTarget(b1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

These 3 files are in the class library project

## Abstract TroopBase class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace ClashOfClans.Units.Troops
{
    public abstract class TroopBase : IAttackable
    {
        public int HP { get; private set; }
        public int Damage { get; private set; }
        public int CostToCreate { get; private set; }
        public Stopwatch TimeAttacking = new Stopwatch();

        public abstract int MoveSpeed { get; }
        public abstract int AttackSpeedMS { get; }
        public abstract double AttackRangeTiles { get; }
        public abstract string Name { get; }

        public int Level { get; set; }

        protected static Dictionary<int, StatStick> LevelStats;

        protected void ApplyStatStick(StatStick stick)
        {
            this.HP = stick.HP;
            this.Damage = stick.Damage;
            this.CostToCreate = stick.Cost;
        }

        protected TroopBase(int level)
        {
            ApplyStatStick(LevelStats[level]);
            AttackTimer = new Timer(this.AttackSpeedMS);
            AttackTimer.Elapsed += AttackTarget;
            this.Level = level;
        }

        public IAttackable Target;

        protected Timer AttackTimer { get; private set; }

        public void EngageTarget(IAttackable target)
        {
            this.Target = target;
            AttackTimer.Start();
            target.Destroyed += TargetDestroyed;
            TimeAttacking.Start();
        }

        protected void AttackTarget(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Target.TakeDamage(this, new AttackEventArgs(this.Damage));
            Console.WriteLine("{1} attacking at {0} time elapsed", TimeAttacking.ElapsedMilliseconds, this.Name);
        }

        public void TakeDamage(object sender, AttackEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} took {1} damage from {2}. {3} hp remaining.",
                this.Name, e.Damage, ((TroopBase)sender).Name, this.HP);
            this.HP -= e.Damage;
            if (HP <= 0)
            {
                OnDestroyed();
            }
        }

        public event Delegates.DestroyedDelegate Destroyed;

        public void OnDestroyed()
        {
            if (Destroyed != null)
            {
                Destroyed(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            this.AttackTimer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} destroyed at {1} time elapsed", this.Name, this.TimeAttacking.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        public void TargetDestroyed(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.AttackTimer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} did {1} damage to {2} and destroyed it!",
                this.Name, this.Damage, (Target as TroopBase).Name);
        }
    }

    public class AttackEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Damage { get; set; }

        public AttackEventArgs(int damage)
        {
            this.Damage = damage;
        }
    }
    public delegate void AttackDelegate(object sender, AttackEventArgs e);

    public class StatStick
    {
        public int HP { get; set; }
        public int Damage { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Goblin

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClashOfClans.Units.Troops
{
    public class Goblin : TroopBase
    {
        public Goblin(int level) : base(level) { }

        public override int MoveSpeed
        {
            get { return 32; }
        }
        public override double AttackRangeTiles
        {
            get { return 0.4D; }
        }
        public override int AttackSpeedMS
        {
            get { return 1000; }
        }
        public override string Name
        {
            get { return "Goblin"; }
        }

        static Goblin()
        {
            LevelStats = new Dictionary<int, StatStick>()
            {
                {1, new StatStick{ HP=25, Damage=11, Cost=25}},
                {2, new StatStick{ HP=30, Damage=14, Cost=40}},
                {3, new StatStick{ HP=36, Damage=19, Cost=60}},
                {4, new StatStick{ HP=43, Damage=24, Cost=80}},
                {5, new StatStick{ HP=52, Damage=32, Cost=100}},
                {6, new StatStick{ HP=68, Damage=42, Cost=150}},
            };
        }
    }
}
```

## IAttackable

```
using ClashOfClans.Units.Troops;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClashOfClans.Units
{
    public class Delegates
    {
        public delegate void DestroyedDelegate(EventArgs e);
    }
    public interface IAttackable
    {
        void TakeDamage(object sender, AttackEventArgs e);
        event Delegates.DestroyedDelegate Destroyed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TakeDamage` method is the issue. You're printing out `this.HP` before accounting for the damage. The 4th attack doesn't *result* in 1 HP left, it happens when 1 HP is left.

1. Goblin has 1 HP left. Barbarian attacks.
2. Print out details of attack (including current 1 HP).
3. Calculate new HP (-7).
4. New HP is less than 0. Call `OnDestroyed`

Comment: Makes sense. I think I just threw the printing in there after I had the logic done, and didn't think about how it would be showing the HP before the damage was applied. Thank you!